# How to build bitcoin from source on Arch Linux 2012.10 64bit?

Tags: installation, compiling

1. Install git

   **pacman -S git**
2. Install bitcoind dependencies as seen here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.txt

   **pacman -S boost boost-libs miniupnpc openssl db**
3. Install arch-linux base development packages so you can use make

   **pacman -S base-devel**
4. Download and install bitcoind from the github source

   **su daemonuser**

   **cd /home/daemonuser**

   **git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git**

   **cd /home/daemonuser/bitcoin/src/**

   **make -f makefile.unix USE_UPNP=- USE_IPV6=0**

   **bitcoind -daemon**

Comment: Do you have a file called "classification.hpp" anywhere on your system? What version of boost did you install? (It looks like you may need a `-I` flag to tell the compiler where `boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp` is.)

Comment: I don't know that much about arch linux, but it looks like you're installing `boost-libs`, which suggests that it only has the libraries. You need to install [boost](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/boost/) as well.

Comment: boost was all that was needed, thank you both!