# When building bitcoind from source, how to specify stable build?

Tags: bitcoind, installation, compiling

I managed to [build bitcoind on arch linux](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10496/how-to-build-bitcoin-from-source-on-arch-linux-2012-10-64bit) after downloading the source from github, but after running bitcoind getinfo command, I am told:

> "errors" : "This is a pre-release test build - use at your own risk -
>   do not use for mining or merchant applications"

How can I remove that message and use a stable build, instead of the pre-release one I downloaded?

I assume I have to do something with the information found here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tags

Comment: great question - you can find this by google searching "This is a pre-release test build - use at your own risk - do not use it for mining or merchant applications"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you got the source via git, you can checkout on the latest stable release tag, currently `v0.8.1` using the git command `git checkout v0.8.1`.

When you did not setup git, you can simply download the source from that tag version from [the webpage you suggested](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tags) using either the .zip or .tar.gz link underneath the tag name. `vX.X.X` releases are stable ones, while the `vX.X.XrcX` releases are release candidates, meaning that they can still contain a few bugs.

Answer (score -1):

The full procedure:

Open a terminal and clone the github repository

```
git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin
```

then get the latest stable version, right now the command is:

```
git fetch
git checkout 0.11
```

then build bitcoin-core as ususal (install the required lib dependencies, ./autogen.sh, ./configure, make, make install)

The current development version is 11.99, you can build multiple version of bitcoin, for example a development version and a stable version to test beta features and to see if the private keys / blockchain / backups are easily loaded on the dev version, this is the json output of the `getinfo` `bitcoin-cli` command/function that lets you check the version numbers:

```
version:         11.9900 
protocolversion:  7.0011 
walletversion:    6.0000
```

this means we are running 0.11.99 (it means the future 0.12)

protocol version is 7.00.11

wallet version is 6

---

extra infos:

the current versions are also stored in JSON on the bitcoin blockchain: 91b37d9429a7e660a6b2c3352e39335e81884493dfbfbffa479b8068194e921d (transaction hash)

https://chain.so/tx/BTC/91b37d9429a7e660a6b2c3352e39335e81884493dfbfbffa479b8068194e921d see the message field on sochain or blockchain.info https://blockchain.info/tx/91b37d9429a7e660a6b2c3352e39335e81884493dfbfbffa479b8068194e921d

Comment: Your answer lacks an explanation on why you should run those commands up top. You should try to refine what you meant.

Comment: done, do you think it is missing something now? could you please rethink about the downvotes, thanks

Comment: Good on you indeed.